# TikZ externalize, pgfplots and animate

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, animate

I gave a very fetching presentation written with beamer today. It included a pgfplot animated with the `animate` package, and the result was fantastic. The problem? One of my colleagues wants to borrow the plot for a presentation written in something non-LaTeX. In addition, it would be nice to know how to externalise animated pgfplots frame by frame for animation using using `convert` or `mencoder` to produce a standalone file for inclusion in websites etc.

Naturally, I turned to `externalize` to do the job for me. It seems that `animate` and `externalize` don't agree... How can I convince them to kiss and make up?

Below is a massively simplified example for the wizards to work with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
% Comment out the following line to see what the plot looks like.
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}\tikzexternalize 

\begin{document}
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
  \multiframe{30}{ind=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
        \addplot {sin(deg(x+\ind*pi/16))};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: the idea when doing `animate` and externalize is to loop (with `\foreach` or equivalent) externalizing the plots (preferably in a separate document). Then you can animate the pdf's after they have been externalized. I did this also by using the overlay feature which can drastically reduce the size of the ouput pdf. If i have time in the following days i will supply what i did in my bachelor thesis.

Comment: @zeroth: I already know how to do that, and it's a lot of effort for something that should be simple (in principle). I'd rather be able to do it this way to keep things neat and easily repeatable.

Comment: i see. I have always done it the other way. I am not sure if what you want is possible, we will see if an answer arrives! :)

Comment: As a bi-product this would improve the time to compile after the first time as TikZ would grab the externalised images for animate.

Comment: Can we see the NOT simplified version of the animation? I am interested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does the animate package do things with the shipout routine of TeX? The external lib replaces it -- probably in an incompatible way.

Nevertheless, the following approach also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
% Comment out the following line to see what the plot looks like.
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize


\begin{document}
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
  \multiframe{30}{ind=0+1}{
    \tikzifexternalizing{%
        Work-around to make animate happy
    }{}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
        \addplot {sin(deg(x+\ind*pi/16))};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
%
\end{document}
```

the statement `\tikzifexternalizing` is only true if one of the frames is being converted. In this case, only the picture of interest makes its way into the output pdf - and we can safely generate non-empty content (and the animate package is happy).

Comment: Very neat! Could be winner.

Comment: I think shipout is probably affected, but I can handle that with a little bash magic. The important thing is just getting the frames out.

Comment: Thanks for your elegant solution @Christian. Animate doesn't tinker with the output routines, it just typesets graphics or inline material into saveboxes and produces Form XObjects (special pdf objects) from them.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the technical background. In case you know the precise reason for the failure: let me know. Perhaps I can fix the external lib. If it is unrelated to `\shipout` hackery, there may be a general fix.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn and Christian: Thank you both for these amazing packages.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the praise :) I'm glad they prove to be useful.

Comment: I have a couple of lines to add to aid in the naming of the externalized files. Do you mind if I add them to this, since it's the accepted answer?

Comment: @Mark feel free if you think they help the audience..

Answer (score 11):

### All in one approach

Read the comments whether or not you need ImageMagick and/or FFMPEG installed on your machine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% create a parameterized template
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \ind in {1,2,...,30}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
        \addplot[color=\clr]  {sin(deg(x+\ind*pi/16))};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{animate}

% creater a PDF file containing frames
%\def\param{red}
%\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=frames "\def\noexpand\clr{\param} \noexpand\input{template}"}

% just another way with \unexpanded to save more keystrokes!
\def\param#1{%
\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{pdflatex -jobname=frames "\def\clr{#1} \input{template}"}}}
\param{blue}

% create a GIF animation (needs ImageMagick installed)
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 5 -loop 0 -density 100 -alpha remove frames.pdf frames.gif}

% create a list of PNG images, one for each frame (needs ImageMagick installed)
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 100 -alpha remove frames.pdf frames-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother

% create a MP4 video (needs both ImageMagick and FFMPEG installed)
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 100 -alpha remove frames.pdf frames-\@percentchar02d.png}
\immediate\write18{ffmpeg -r 5 -i frames-\@percentchar02d.png -vcodec libx264 frames.mp4}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% create a PDF animation
\begin{center}
    \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{frames}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### GIF output

[image]

### PNG output

I will not show all as they will waste your bandwidth.

[image]

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to use `pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename.tex` to compile the given code above.

Comment: I know it's "against the rules", but I just had to thank you for this – awesome answer!

Comment: @kissmyarmpit I'll kiss your armpit for this great answer :p

Answer (score 10):

`\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and package `animate` don't work well together.

`\tikzexternalize` moves the `tikzpicture` environment into an external file to be processed separately (therefore, `--shell-escape` must be activated) and replaces the `tikzpicture` environment with `\includegraphics`.

On the first pass when no external pdf graphics are available, the boxes into which the `animateinline` environment stores the code it encloses have zero size. `animate` measures the box dimensions of the first frame and scales the animation widget accordingly. There is a built-in stop condition in `animate` when it finds that the box is empty.

To work-around this, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
% Comment out the following line to see what the plot looks like.
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\newlength\mywidth
\newlength\myheight
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \def\ind{0}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
      \addplot {sin(deg(x+\ind*pi/16))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
\settowidth\mywidth{\usebox\mybox}
\settoheight\myheight{\usebox\mybox}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
  \multiframe{30}{ind=0+1}{
    \makebox[\mywidth][l]{\rule{0pt}{\myheight}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
          \addplot {sin(deg(x+\ind*pi/16))};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}
%
\end{document}
```

An easy way to produce a standalone, correctly sized multipage PDF of all animation frames is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
%
\newcounter{ind}%
\whiledo{\theind<30}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=3.14]
      \addplot {sin(deg(x+\theind*pi/16))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \stepcounter{ind}%
  \newpage%
}
%
\end{document}
```

This multipage PDF can be further converted to other formats, such as SWF:

```
pdf2swf frames.pdf
swfcombine -r10 --output frames10fps.swf --dummy frames.swf
```

Comment: I actually debated whether or not to use `article` or `standalone` with myself (my code didn't work with either) and should have stuck with the former as being in `article` is fine as far as the code is concerned. Note however that the original diagram is in beamer which I ruled out immediately. I like your answer, but as noted in the comments I already know of a way to do it independently of animate. I'd rather use animate and external together if it can be achieved.

Comment: @Mark: See my edit which makes animate and external work more or less smoothly together.

Comment: Thanks, but your first block of code gives me some errors...

Comment: @Mark. Everything ok on my side (copied back the code into a new file and ran `pdflatex  --shell-escape` on it.)

Comment: Oh strange. It works perfectly now! It even works in standalone. ;) This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies; I marked Christian's answer as correct because it's easier to implement. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: @Mark. I completely agree, I would have done the same.