# Cross-referencing within tikzpicture mixes with frontespizio package

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, frontespizio

I'm trying to create a plot, using `pgfplots` and the `externalize` library, which contains a `\label` to a plot and a corresponding `\ref` in a legend.
I'm also using the `frontespizio` package to create the first page.

When I run `pdflatex` the first time, the reference in the plot is not resolved and I get the usual ?? where the `\ref` should be.
After the second run (plus a `pdflatex test-frn` to create the PDF of the frontispice), that terminates without any error, the label gets placed, but the plot appears with the frontispice (which then appears *two* times in the output) in the background.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat = 1.14,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{filecontents}{frontespizio-test.tex}
    \begin{frontespizio}
        \Universita{X}
        \Facolta{prova}
        \Corso{x}
        \Titoletto{tesi}
        \Titolo{titolo}
        \Candidato{Io}
        \Relatore{Un altro}
        \Correlatore{Qualcun altro}
        \Annoaccademico{2016-2017}
    \end{frontespizio}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{frontespizio-test}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test-figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=prova,
                    rows=2,
                    columns=2
                }
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}; \label{x}
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \addlegendentry{\ref{x}}
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I really need to externalize the plots, since I'm working with many "heavy" plots, and I need the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism to manually create a legend for the `groupplot`, as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192433/44686) answer.

**Update**: the frontispice appears in *every* plot that is externalised, also those without inner references, without a `groupplot` environment, even in a drawing of a molecule created with `chemfig`.

This is how it looks like using the code in egreg's answer:
[image: Frontispice on the background of externalised plots]

Comment: A solution could be based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39001/tikz-externalize-pgfplots-and-animate : perhaps you can move `\input{frontespizio-test}` into `\tikzifexternalizing{}{\input...}` such that it is _only_ done for the main file, not for the externalized images

Comment: Thanks, this works! I have to use `mode=list and make` and compile many times to get the labels right, but at least I have a correct output.

Answer (score 1):

I get only one frontispiece, if I use the package according to the documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat = 1.14,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize


\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
  \Universita{X}
  \Facolta{prova}
  \Corso{x}
  \Titoletto{tesi}
  \Titolo{titolo}
  \Candidato{Io}
  \Relatore{Un altro}
  \Correlatore{Qualcun altro}
  \Annoaccademico{2016-2017}
\end{frontespizio}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test-figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=prova,
                    rows=2,
                    columns=2
                }
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}; \label{x}
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \addlegendentry{\ref{x}}
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test-figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=prova,
                    rows=2,
                    columns=2
                }
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)}; \label{y}
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \addlegendentry{\ref{y}}
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your code verbatim in a new file, but I still see the frontispiece behind the plots.

Comment: @yellowquark I don't. Who wins?